# Adapting Modal Dialog Script to Firefox

Tags: watir, autoit, firewatir

I'm adapting my regression tests to test a web app in firefox. The biggest stumbling block seems to be how to automate the modal dialogs in firefox.

In ie I use variations of the script below, but it doesn't work in Firefox. Is there an alternative that will work in both ie and firefox?

```
popup=Thread.new {
    autoit=WIN32OLE.new('AutoItX3.Control')
    ret=autoit.WinWait(title,"",60)
    if (ret==1)
        puts "There is popup."
        autoit.WinActivate(title)
        button.downcase!
        if button.eql?("ok") || button.eql?("yes") || button.eql?("continue")
            autoit.Send("{Enter}")
        else
            autoit.Send("{tab}")
            autoit.Send("{Enter}")
        end
    elsif (ret==0)
        puts "No popup, please check your code."
    end
}
at_exit { Thread.kill(popup) }
end

   button.click_no_wait

   check_for_popups("Message from webpage", "OK")
```

Comment: any chance of a link to a page that would show an example of the popup you are facing?

Comment: Sorry. I just saw this reply. The type of popup i'm running across is like the first one on this page (http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/JavaScript+Pop+Ups). Where it confirms a user's action.

Comment: en light of that, I've completely revised my proposed answer below

Answer (score 2):

Given you are talking about a javascript created dialog, I really have to ask, is there a lot of value in actually testing those?

It basically amounts to testing the functionality of the browser

If you are talking about the type of popups described here http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/JavaScript+Pop+Ups  then I think the first solution, of overriding the javascript may well be your best cross platform option.

The problem with modal dialogs like this is that they are basically a UI even that is happening out at the OS level, it's no longer inside the browser DOM, and thus you need tools that are specific to the OS (like stuff that depends on win32ole, such as autoit) in order to generate the necessary interaction with the native UI and click buttons, send keystrokes etc.    Most of the solutions presented should I think work with FF on windows (with proper renaming of expected window titles etc) but would fail on a mac or *nix OS.   That means you need a different solution for each OS, which is a pain.

It might simply be easier to verify you can find the proper stuff that would fire the event in the HTML of the page, so you know an event WOULD be fired, and then override things so it isn't.  After all it's not really your job to validate that the browser pops up a local dialog when something like `alert('This is an alert box')` is invoked in javascript.  Your concern is that in the HTML a given element is coded to fire off the event that is needed  e.g. that there's something like this  `onClick = 'javascript:x = confirm('Do you really want to do this');"` affiliated with the element

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing a similar problem in Firefox (and I do have to test in Firefox).  I can see the code calling the Javascript but when I try to override as described above nothing happens.  Is there any kind of a workaround for this?  Anticipated updates to Watir? ;-)

Comment: I didn't find a great solution. But what i did was use a rescue statement. So when it fails the method that works in Firefox fails in IE it'll move on to the one that works in ie. The outlines of my code is below. 
     begin
       b.startClicker("OK")  
       b.button(:id, "Button to Click").click 
     rescue NoMethodError
       b.execute_script("window.confirm = function() {return true}")
       b.button(:id, "Button to Click").click  
      end
    end